Ros2 Canopen Change axis for motor
I running into a problem about my real hardware robot.
When building the robot the right wheel motor was installed the other way around, meaning that when the wheel rotates forward in real life, the odometry believes it is rotating backward. About the left wheel, there is a normal behavior: rotating forward in real life make the odometry move forward too.
I tried to modify the urdf to match the movement of the wheel but now the problem is only occurring for the odometry. Now both wheel moves OK but odometry still does not have a correct behavior ( rotating when should be forwarding and vice-versa )
Is there a way in ros2-canopen to modify the config and tell the controller one wheel is mounted the other way around.
I would like as mush as possible to not have to disassemble and reassemble it.

TBH I would make life easy and just disassemble and mount the motor the right way around - or you might be able to simply swap the wires round if that's easier to access.
